# SQL case statement that converts this SAS code using IF, THEN DO, into SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, case

I need to do this for work as we are transforming some of our SAS programs into SQL as part of an ongoing project. This is the SAS code that I need to change into SQL case statement:

```
if Patients1 in (08,09,10) or (Patients1=41 and HospAttend=' Yes') then do;
        if Patients2 ne 23 then AdmitResult='1. Patient Type A';
        else if Patients2 =23 then AdmitResult='2. Patient Type B';
    end;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? What are you stuck on? And FYI, `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: First of all, SQL will not be a direct replacement and is a poor choice. If you have a chance, use an ORM vs direct SQL. Not all SAS statements will lend themselves to conversion. For example, FIRST. and LAST. will be problematic. An ORM will mitigate this issue. I use C# and EF to handle these types of problems. Consider doing something similar. The above is simple in python/C#. Then, let the ORM decide the SQL for you and where it can use SQL vs not.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the code should do.

Answer (score 0):

As a `case` **expression** this would be:

```
(case when Patients1 in ('08', '09', '10') or
           (Patients1 = '41' and HospAttend = ' Yes') 
      then (case when Patients2 <> 23 then '1. Patient Type A';
                 else '2. Patient Type B'
            end)
 end) as AdmitResult;
```

Note:  The leading zeros on `Patients1` suggest that the values are strings.  If they are numbers, remove both the single quotes and the leading zeros (the leading zeros are misleading in that case).

Also, the space in `' Yes'` is meaningful and you might not really need it.  Strings are not usually stored with leading spaces.